# Making butch upsert in mongodb: callback never fired

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I have an array of documents with unique _id and I want to insert them to my database. Some of them already in db, and for those I want to update an array property (push in array an item). All of this I need to make asyncronuosly, so after all inserted/updated I want to write response back (with callback) to client than all ok or write an error. After googling on subject I've found this [solution with async module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092630/node-js-mongodb-inserting-updating-multiple-documents-and-sending-a-single-re) I've tried to implement it for my case. Now my code looks like this:

```
function processUsers(arr, listName, callback) {

    var users = global.db.collection('vkusers');
    var q = async.queue(function(task, cb) {
        console.log('upsert butch');
        users.insert(task.doc, function(err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                users.update({
                    _id : task.doc._id
                }, {
                    $addToSet : {
                        mLists : listName
                    }
                }, function(error, result){ console.log(error); console.log(result); });
            }

        });

    }, arr.length);

    for ( var doc in arr) {
        q.push({
            doc : arr[doc]
        }, function(err) {
            if (err)
                callback(err, null);
        })
    }
    q.drain = function() {
        // this is the queue's callback, called when the queue is empty,
        // i.e. when all your documents have been processed.
        console.log('drain');
        callback(null, { result: "success", upserted: arr.length });
    }

}
```

Callback has signature callback(error, result), arr - my array of documents. I've tested it and with database everything is OK, i am getting the right result. But callback, and q.drain never fired!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `async.queue`'s callback (`cb` in your code) when your insert/update is complete.  Something like this:

```
var q = async.queue(function(task, cb) {
    console.log('upsert butch');
    users.insert(task.doc, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            users.update({
                _id : task.doc._id
            }, {
                $addToSet : {
                    mLists : listName
                }
            }, function(error, result) { 
                console.log(error); 
                console.log(result); 

                cb(error); // Update finished; call cb and pass in "error" so that it can bubble up if it exists
            });
        } else {
            cb(); // Insert succeeded; call cb
        }
    });

}, arr.length);
```